# How do I specify an image style in my preprocess function?

Tags: theming, media

In my current project, whenever a node's image field is empty, I'm filling it with the image from an entity referenced in the node. To pull this off, I'm using this magical piece of code in template.php:

```
// Implements hook_preprocess_node();
    function mycustomtheme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {

      $node = $vars['node'];
      $field_name = 'field_main_image';
      if (
        isset($node->$field_name) &&
        empty($node->$field_name)
      ) {
        $node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
        if ($node_wrapper->field_master_reference->raw()) {
          $project = $node_wrapper->field_master_reference->value();
          $vars['content'][$field_name] = field_view_field('node', $project, $field_name);
        }
      }
    }
```

It works superbly - but with one small problem: it doesn't give the image its correct image style. In fact it just spits out the original image.

How can I force it to use the field's image style?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to use the API function called `image_style_url` which can pull in specific image styles. I just don't have time right now to give a fully fleshed out answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Danny. That's going to be it. I'll investigate and see if I can work out how to incorporate it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [`render`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/render/7)

```
// Implements hook_preprocess_node();
    function mycustomtheme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {

      $node = $vars['node'];
      $field_name = 'field_main_image';
      if (
        isset($node->$field_name) &&
        empty($node->$field_name)
      ) {
        $node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
        if ($node_wrapper->field_master_reference->raw()) {
          $project = $node_wrapper->field_master_reference->value();
          $vars['content'][$field_name] = render($vars['content'][$field_name]);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, Nikhil. Unfortunately, this breaks the original function - I assume it's because the $project variable is responsible for the image swapping.